# Magento allow customers to have a credit limit

Tags: magento-1.7, limit, user-accounts, credits

I need some customers to be able to log in to an account and once they log in they can choose invoice as the payment method. I have found some very expensive extensions but I am looking to see if there is an easier way to do this? And if there are any options to use the out of box features for this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the Bank Transfer or the Purchase Order payment methods for this? They should be just fine - except if you have some additional requirements like credit limit.